# Apache mod_rewrite: explain me %{HTTP_HOST} especially when using addon domains

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, dns, add-on, http-host

Apache mod_rewrite: explain me %{HTTP_HOST} expecially when using addon domains

Situation (directories tree) on an Apache server with addon domains:

```
main-domain.com/ 
| 
|_ .htaccess (just an empty file, no rule in here) 
|_ index.html (shown when accessing http://main-domain.com)
| 
|_ addon-domain-1.com/ 
|  | 
|  |_ .htaccess 
|  |_ index.html (shown when accessing http://addon-domain-1.com or http://main-domain.com/addon-domain-1.com/)
| 
|_ addon-domain-2.com/ 
   | 
   |_ .htaccess 
   |_ index.html (shown when accessing http://addon-domain-2.com or http://main-domain.com/addon-domain-2.com/)
```

Let's say in "addon-domain-1.com/.htaccess" file I have some rule using %{HTTP_HOST} like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^something$
```

**Does `%{HTTP_HOST}` evaluates to the domain of the currently requested url on server???**

So if asking for:

http://addon-domain-1.com/

```
%{HTTP_HOST} will be "addon-domain-1.com"?
```

http://addon-domain-1.com (without final slash)

```
%{HTTP_HOST} will still be "addon-domain-1.com"?
```

http://www.addon-domain-1.com

```
%{HTTP_HOST} will still be "www.addon-domain-1.com"?
```

And when asking for:

http://main-domain.com/addon-domain-1.com

```
%{HTTP_HOST} will be "main-domain.com"???
or "main-domain.com/addon-domain-1.com"???
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pretty much guessed them all right! The last one would be;

```
main-domain.com
```

Answer (score 6):

`%{HTTP_*}` evaluates to the HTTP header with the name given after the prefix shown. In HTTP 1.1, the host being accessed is given in the `Host` header, so yes.

Comment: And this means, that the client sends the contents of the variable. You can not trust anything from the client. And you should not use untrusted data in a rewrite rule.